# Wrong file not found exception

Tags: c#, dll, filenotfoundexception, flycapture, gige-sdk

I'm programming in C# using FlyCapture2 SDK (for point grey cameras) for GigE cameras. I debugged my code in my Laptop. It works in my laptop. I run it in my NUC PC (NUC is a mini pc produced by intel) and I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in ALPRX.exe
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'FlyCapture2Managedd_v140.dll' or one of its dependencies. The
>   specified module could not be found.

I have `FlyCapture2Managedd_v140.dll` in debug folder. Also I follow dependencies from SDK. As mentioned in error named library may have several dependencies itself. How can I find dll dependencies or how can I fix this problem?

Excuse me for my bad English

Comment: How did you deploy the app to your NUC?

Comment: I copy my app to NUC. Also I installed vs 2015 and debug my app in NUC6 (skull Canyon) locally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall x64 FlyCapture2 SDK and reinstall x86.

Reload the solution(project).
Modify the reference to x86 version of FlyManageXXXXX.dll.
Configure the platform to x86 (not x64, not any CPU) and rebuild it.
works for me. You could have a try and please report your result to let more people to know how to fix it.